# Generate a prime which divides a prime - 1

Tags: prime-numbers

I generated a random prime $p$. Now I want to find a random prime with a fixed size of $256$ Bits which divides $p - 1$. $p$ has $3072$ Bits, so I can't just try it out.

Comment: Do you know that such a prime exists in your case? Usually it won't.

Comment: No, I don't, but I hoped some one knows an algorithm, which could tell me if one exists and, if so, which prime it is.

Comment: @91378246: such algorithm would have solved the factorization problem and broken RSA. Given some large integer (integers of the form $p-1$ are not really special) there is no simple (polynomial) way to get a divisor, but you may employ sieve methods (like the quadratic sieve) to find divisors in some range, then a primality test (AKS *is* polynomial, for instance) to select *prime* divisors. Anyway, it will be computationally expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into that.